# This is an implementation of a Vector in C in 27 lines written by Sean Barrett. Could someone explain to me how this works?

Tags: c

From here: [A tidy little C implementation of stretchy buffers (aka C++ vectors)](http://nothings.org/stb/stretchy_buffer.txt) The code's description says this:

> declare an empty buffer with something like 'mytype *myarray = NULL', and then use the sb*() functions to manipulate; read/write individual elements by indexing as usual

I should preface this by saying that I only know really a little bit of C, and this is essentially uncharted territory. I have never used double pointers, void pointers, or any memory functions like realloc. Could someone explain what is happening all over this code in plain english? It uses a lot of fancy macro definitions that I do not understand, which leaves me wondering what it would look like written out proper.

The code:

```
  // stretchy buffer // init: NULL // free: sbfree() // push_back: sbpush() // size: sbcount() //
    #define sbfree(a)         ((a) ? free(stb__sbraw(a)),0 : 0)
    #define sbpush(a,v)       (stb__sbmaybegrow(a,1), (a)[stb__sbn(a)++] = (v))
    #define sbcount(a)        ((a) ? stb__sbn(a) : 0)
    #define sbadd(a,n)        (stb__sbmaybegrow(a,n), stb__sbn(a)+=(n), &(a)[stb__sbn(a)-(n)])
    #define sblast(a)         ((a)[stb__sbn(a)-1])

    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define stb__sbraw(a) ((int *) (a) - 2)
    #define stb__sbm(a)   stb__sbraw(a)[0]
    #define stb__sbn(a)   stb__sbraw(a)[1]

    #define stb__sbneedgrow(a,n)  ((a)==0 || stb__sbn(a)+n >= stb__sbm(a))
    #define stb__sbmaybegrow(a,n) (stb__sbneedgrow(a,(n)) ? stb__sbgrow(a,n) : 0)
    #define stb__sbgrow(a,n)  stb__sbgrowf((void **) &(a), (n), sizeof(*(a)))

    static void stb__sbgrowf(void **arr, int increment, int itemsize)
    {
       int m = *arr ? 2*stb__sbm(*arr)+increment : increment+1;
       void *p = realloc(*arr ? stb__sbraw(*arr) : 0, itemsize * m + sizeof(int)*2);
       assert(p);
       if (p) {
          if (!*arr) ((int *) p)[1] = 0;
          *arr = (void *) ((int *) p + 2);
          stb__sbm(*arr) = m;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could someone assist me with this code formatting? I can't seem to get it to work precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial advice would be to ignore this code and move on to something else. You're unlikely to learn anything of much use from analyzing this code.

If you insist on understanding it, the basic idea is pretty simple. The rest is mostly just fiddly details.

The basics: it manages an array. The first element of the array is used to hold the currently allocated size of the array. The second element is used to hold the number of elements currently in use. It has replacements for the normal operators to let you get to specific elements in "your" part of the array it allocated (i.e., since array[0] and array[1] are used for its own housekeeping, when you ask for element[n], it gives you array[n+2]).

From there, it's mostly a matter of keeping track of the currently used size versus the currently allocated size, and allocating a larger array when needed. It can/will also free the whole array when you tell it to (with `stb_free`).

Comment: Would you mind pointing me in the direction of a vector implementation in C that is worth studying? Thanks.

Comment: @misterMatt: Right offhand, I can't think of any -- most C tends more toward assuring against overrunning a fixed-size buffer than resizing the buffer as needed.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but can you elaborate why this code is bad in some way?

Comment: @CharlesW Particularly the complete mess of function-like macros, that fill no purpose expect making the program unreadable. But also  excessive use of the ?: operator that does not improve readability, nonsense macro and variable names, casts back and forth between void* and int* instead of using int* in the first place, inconsistent indention, abuse of the comma operator etc etc. Just truly awful code.

Comment: @Lundin Just to clarify for any aspiring C developers, the usage of ?: and comma operator are not objectively bad. C is also sometimes considered a spartan language, and so it is not uncommon to see macros, functions, and variables with short names. To your point, the casting takes place twice whenever the array is resized instead of once, and the indentation could be better.

Comment: @CharlesW There are valid uses of `?:` and those are the cases where it leads to more readable code than if-else. As for the comma operator, it is a completely superfluous feature. More often than not, it is used for obfuscation purposes. You can write any program without it. For example, the comma operator is banned by MISRA-C.

Comment: @Lundin The comma operator allows for the macro to be embedded within a conditional.

Comment: @CharlesW And...? Just because you have a scenario "in order to obfuscate my program through bad practice X, I must obscure feature Y", it doesn't make obscure feature Y a useful programming feature. The main problem is the need to obfuscate the program to begin with, which originates from muddy program design and/or outdated knowledge about how optimizing compilers work.

Comment: This is a bit late, but how does one use this stretchy buffer? I have read the header comments but haven't found a full usage example. The in-line comments suggest that I just pass to a stretchy buffer function a null pointer (to the type I want), but that doesn't seem right alone. Do I also need to define a particular struct somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

In the code, a stretchy buffer is similar to a `struct` with three elements

1. `int sbm`: The number of elements in the buffer.
2. `int sbn`: The number of elements the buffer can grow to without needing to reallocate.
3. `???`: Your data (unknown type and size).

When you create a buffer, the code returns a pointer to the "your data" part, and so uses negative offsets from that to get to the other two fields.  Because a `NULL` buffer pointer is treated as an empty buffer, that needs to be special cased in many places.  The code that is like `(a) ? x : y` is saying that if `a` is `NULL`, return `x`, otherwise return `y`.

There are a few idioms that are macro versions of common C constructs:

1. `a, b` == `a; b;`.
2. `p ? x : y` == `if (p) a; else b;`.

Uses of macro parameters are generally put in extra parentheses, as are macro definitions, to make the macro safe to use with expressions as arguments and so the macro can be put into the middle of an expression.

When you add `n` elements, the code tests whether `sbm + n` is greater than `sbn`; if it is, `realloc` is used to create a new buffer and `sbn` is reset to the larger size.  Your data is then put in.

Answer (score 2):

As a start:

```
// Given a, return a 'raw a', being two integers below a.
// Those two access by the following calls.
#define stb__sbraw(a) ((int *) (a) - 2)

// The current number opf elements in the array; same as count
#define stb__sbm(a)   stb__sbraw(a)[0]
// The number of elements available to the current storage
#define stb__sbn(a)   stb__sbraw(a)[1]
```

So:

```
// Free the raw storage
 #define sbfree(a)         ((a) ? free(stb__sbraw(a)),0 : 0)
```

stb__sbgrowf does all the allocation; if initially passed a pointer to null it will create the two integer header automatically.

Comment: I was exactly after the explanation on how that code figures out array size.Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I made my own stretchy buffer for personal use, it is simple. Let's start with testing code, that shows the usage of such buffer/vector.

```
void buf_test()
{
        int *ints = NULL;
        enum { N = 1024 };
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                buf_push(ints, i);
        }
        assert(buf_len(ints) == N);

        for (int i = 0; i < buf_len(ints); i++) {
                assert(ints[i] == i);
        }
}
```

From here we see, that `ints` can point to the array, or `NULL`. It is actually an array, and you can access elements as usual `ints[i]`. But it is dynamically allocated, and somehow we need to store its `length` and `capacity`.

```
typedef struct {
        size_t len;
        size_t cap;
        char buf[0];
} Bufhdr;
```

Some macros help us to access that structure.

```
#define buf__hdr(b) ((Bufhdr *) ((size_t *) b - 2))
#define buf__len(b) ((b) ? buf__hdr(b)->len : 0)
#define buf__cap(b) ((b) ? buf__hdr(b)->cap : 0)
```

And decide when to grow our vector.

```
#define buf__fits(b, n) (buf__len(b) + (n) <= buf__cap(b))
#define buf__grow(b, n) buf_grow((b), buf__len(b) + (n), sizeof(*(b)))
#define buf__fit(b, n) (buf__fits(b, n) ? 0 : ((b) = buf__grow(b, n)))
```

`buf_push` and `buf_len` is actually some fancy macros, but operations is simple. It is common practice to implement certain data structures using macros.

```
#define buf_len(b) buf__hdr(b)->len
#define buf_push(b, x) (buf__fit(b, 1), b[buf_len(b)++] = (x))
```

The only thing left is one function:

```
void *buf_grow(const void *buf, size_t len, size_t elem_size)
{
        size_t new_cap, new_size;
        Bufhdr *hdr;

        new_cap = buf__cap(buf) ? 2 * buf__cap(buf) : len;
        assert(len <= new_cap);
        new_size = offsetof(Bufhdr, buf) + new_cap * elem_size;

        if (buf) {
                hdr = realloc(buf__hdr(buf), new_size);
        } else {
                hdr = malloc(new_size);
                hdr->len = 0;
        }
        hdr->cap = new_cap;
        return hdr->buf;
}
```

You can use a pointer to any type — buffer will automatically allocate needed memory based on `sizeof(*buf)`

You can further extend this to your needs, for example

```
#define buf_reserve(b, n) buf_grow((b), (n), sizeof(*(b))
#define buf_free(b) ((b) ? free(buf__hdr(b)) : 0)
```

Comment: This is not a Custom Implementation unless your Name is actually Per Vognsen. Who is actually the author of this code. Which he wrote live on stream on Mar 12 2018. You can view the YouTube video of him writing it here: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6TyvsKo_KI&list=PLU94OURih-CiP4WxKSMt3UcwMSDM3aTtX&index=2)

Source Code here:[link](https://github.com/pervognsen/bitwise/blob/master/ion/common.c)